# Can PyLaTex divide my pages into sections?

Tags: python, pdf, ms-word, pdf-generation, pylatex

I need to create academic transcripts similar to the one I attached below.

The problem now is table placement.
As you can see, after the biodata section, the rest of the pdf (or word) document is tables.
But the pages are divided into two sections

Left and Right.

Is there anyway to have PyLaTeX move to the right side automatically when the left is full before moving to the next page.

I considered creating special rules for each table but the problem with that is that the tables don't all have the same height so it creates inconsistencies.

If PyLaTeX can't implement this functionality directly, I'd appreciate any unique approaches or library recommendations that you think can get the job done.
Hold nothing back.

In Word or pdf format.

Thank you for your help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zq7v5.png)